# Select from Table B which feeds Table E - pull records which do and do not exist in E from B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've 2 Tables - E & B which are linked by the column Breaktime. Table B contains all available times and feeds them to Table E. If a time is not used by Table E, then the record for that time no longer appears in Table E. I need to select * from E to obtain the used times but also need the times not used which are not in E but are in B and mark them as "Unused". The query has a lot of parameters, so here's the short version:

```
SELECT 
    e.BreakDate, b.Breaktime,
        (CASE WHEN...) to separate the times into categories
FROM
    event e, break b, *several more tables*
WHERE
    e.breakdate = b.breakdate
and e.breaktime = b.breaktime
and *linking additional tables*
```

I've tried using

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT e.breaktime FROM E,B WHERE e.breaktime = b.breaktime)
```

and I've tried using

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT e.breaktime
    FROM E,B
    WHERE e.breaktime = b.breaktime
) THEN (
    SELECT b.breaktime
    FROM E,B
    where NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM E,B
        WHERE e.breaktime = b.breaktime
    )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider selecting from `B` like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM B
    LEFT JOIN E ...
```

By performing the `LEFT JOIN` you'll get **all rows** from `B` and **matching rows** from `E`. Bear in mind that you will get *more than one* row of `B` values because they will exist for every matching row in `E`. The data might look like this:

```
B.Field1          B.Field2          E.Field1
============================================
1                 A                 NULL
2                 B                 Value 1
2                 B                 Value 2
```

The row where `E.Field1` is `NULL` means there is **no** matching row in `E` for that `B`. By contrast, notice that the `B` fields *seem* duplicated. And at some level they are. But that's because there is **more than one** matching `E` for that `B`.

You can easily abstract this now, even just mentally, to where you could do some grouping and distinct manipulations of sub queries to ensure you only got what you wanted from `E`. Maybe you make an inner query like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM E
WHERE E.field IN (
    SELECT e.field
    FROM B
        LEFT JOIN E ...
    GROUP BY ....
)
```

That's just an example.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  Took a little tweaking, but worked!

Comment: @MichelleAlston, I'm glad I could be of assistance!